# How to save Word.Range into document

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-word, office-interop

I'm trying to copy all text from one Word document and to replace into other Word document.
I opened and copied all text from source document into Word.Range after I found the text that must be replaced in destination document (with Word.Range) and I replace founded Range with Range from source document:

```
 'Find and Replace in destination Document
  Dim wordRangeFind As Word.Range = destWordDoc.Content
  wordRangeFind.Find.Execute(findText)
  wordRangeFind = wordRange
```

In debug I see that wordRangeFind are changed with wordRange but destWordDoc.Content remains as it was. After destWordDoc.Save() i see the file without changes.
Can you write me please, how can i save Word.Range into Word document.
Here are my function:

```
  'Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

  Dim missing As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
  Dim sourceWordApp As Word.Application = New Word.Application()
  sourceWordApp.Visible = False
  'Open source Document
  Dim sourceWordDoc As Word.Document = sourceWordApp.Documents.Open(sourceWordFile, missing, False,
                                      missing, missing, missing,
                                      missing, missing, missing,
                                      missing, missing, missing,
                                      missing, missing, missing, missing)
  'Open destination Document
  Dim destWordApp As Word.Application = New Word.Application()
  destWordApp.Visible = False
  Dim destWordDoc As Word.Document = destWordApp.Documents.Open(destWordFile, missing, False,
                                      missing, missing, missing,
                                      missing, missing, missing,
                                      missing, missing, missing,
                                      missing, missing, missing, missing)

  destWordDoc.Activate()
  'Get all text from source Document
  Dim wordRange As Word.Range = sourceWordDoc.Range(missing, missing)

  'Find and Replace in destination Document
  Dim wordRangeFind As Word.Range = destWordDoc.Content
  wordRangeFind.Find.Execute(findText)
  wordRangeFind = wordRange

  'Save and close dest Document
  destWordDoc.Save()
  destWordDoc.Close(missing, missing, missing)
  sourceWordDoc.Close(missing, missing, missing)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my Problem otherwise (without to save Range) but with Copy() and Paste() functions.
Here is my code:

```
  Dim missing As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
  Dim sourceWordApp As Word.Application = New Word.Application()
  sourceWordApp.Visible = False
  'Open source Document
  Dim sourceWordDoc As Word.Document = sourceWordApp.Documents.Open(sourceWordFile, missing, False,
                                      missing, missing, missing,
                                      missing, missing, missing,
                                      missing, missing, missing,
                                      missing, missing, missing, missing)
  'Open destination Document
  Dim destWordApp As Word.Application = New Word.Application()
  destWordApp.Visible = False
  Dim destWordDoc As Word.Document = destWordApp.Documents.Open(destWordFile, missing, False,
                                      missing, missing, missing,
                                      missing, missing, missing,
                                      missing, missing, missing,
                                      missing, missing, missing, missing)

  destWordDoc.Activate()
  'Copy all text from source Document
  sourceWordApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory()
  sourceWordApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy()

  'Find in destination Document
  Dim wordRangeFind As Word.Range = destWordDoc.Content
  wordRangeFind.Find.Execute(findText)
  wordRangeFind.Text = ""
  wordRangeFind.Select()
  
  'Paste copied text into dest document
  destWordDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Paste()

  'Save and close dest document
  destWordDoc.Save()
  destWordDoc.Close(missing, missing, missing)
  sourceWordDoc.Close(missing, missing, missing)
```